# Symfony 1.4 - sfCacheSessionStorage

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am working on implementing memcached (with igbinary api) within my SF 1.4 app, and have run into an issue, and need insight into how to proceed.

Basically I created my own caching class which extends sfCacheSessionStorage and overrides these methods: `initialize`, `regenerate`, and `shutdown`. I had to override these methods b/c they all make calls to PHP's serialize api, but I prefer to use the igbinary serialization api instead.

After getting everything in place, I noticed that `sfCacheSessionStorage::regenerate()` creates it's own session id, with no regard to whether the session was already regenerated. For example in the parent `sfSessionStorage::regenerate()` class, there is a singleton used to determine if the session has already been regenerated. This avoids issues where session data may be lost b/c it was associated with a previously regenerated session_id and not carried over to the newly regenerated session_id.

SF 1.4 will call the `regenerate()` method anytime you flag a user as authenticated (logged in), logged out, and if you clear/add credentials. The problem I have is after the user is flagged as authenticated, I call a listener which clears credentials and adds any group associations, this results in two calls to `sfCacheSessionStorage::regenerate()`, where the session data is lost. However, if I edit the cookie, and set it to the first regenerated session_id, the session behaves as expected, it's the 2nd call (caused by the clear credentials) that the session data is lost due to a newly regenerated session id.

My idea is to follow the logic of sfSessionStorage, and use a singleton to determine if the session was already regenerated, however there may be a reason why `sfCacheSessionStorage::regenerate()` regenerates the session EVERYTIME. So my question is, am I safe to proceed with the singleton strategy, or should I try to get the EVERYTIME regeneration working? It's my understand that the ONLY reason to regenerate the session_id when logging in/out or adding/removing credentials is to avoid the [session fixation](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation) hijacking scenario.

- Source code for [sfSessionStorage](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/storage/sfSessionStorage.class.php)
- Source code for [sfCacheSessionStorage](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/storage/sfCacheSessionStorage.class.php)

My code is exactly the same, save for the serialize/unserialize calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding in the singleton as mentioned in OP, to avoid needless, multiple session_id regenerations. Also, I added a check around the `$this->cache->set` call, as it made no sense to store an empty array in cache, rather the `shutdown()` method will do that for us.